# Looping through a PostgreSQL table in bash

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table of the following format:

```
uid  |    defaults  |  settings
-------------------------------
abc  |   ab, bc     |     -
     |              |
pqr  |   pq, ab     |     -
     |              |
xyz  |   xy, pq     |     -
```

I am trying to list all the uids which contain ab in the `defaults` column. In the above case, `abc` and `pqr` must be listed.

How do I form the query and loop it around the table to check each row in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really about bash but you can call your query command using psql. You can try this format:

```
psql -U username -d database_name -c "SELECT uid FROM table_name WHERE defaults LIKE 'ab, %' OR defaults LIKE '%, ab'
```

Or maybe simply

```
psql -U username -d database_name -c "SELECT uid FROM table_name WHERE defaults LIKE '%ab%'
```

`-U username` is optional.

Comment: I find this simpler. The query returns what I need but it also returns `ab` if `ab` is under uid

Comment: I made a correction on the first one. `'*, ab'` should have been `'%, ab'`.

Answer (score 3):

[@user000001 already provided the bash part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18229746/939860). And the query could be:

```
SELECT uid
FROM   tbl1
WHERE  defaults LIKE '%ab%'
```

But this is inherently **unreliable**, since this would also find 'fab' or 'abz'. It is also hard to create a fast index.

Consider **normalizing** your schema. Meaning you would have another 1:n table `tbl2` with entries for individual defaults and a foreign key to `tbl1`. Then your query could be:

```
SELECT uid
FROM   tbl1 t1
WHERE  EXISTS
   (SELECT 1
    FROM   tbl2 t2
    WHERE  t2.def = 'ab'  -- "default" = reserved word in SQL, so I use "def"
    AND    t2.tbl1_uid = t1.uid);
```

Or at least use an **array** for `defaults`. Then your query would be:

```
SELECT uid
FROM   tbl1
WHERE  'ab' = ANY (defaults);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use awk:

```
awk -F\| '$2~/ab/{print $1}' file
```

Explanation:

- The `-F\|` sets the field seperator to the `|` character
- With `$2~/ab/` we filter the lines that contain "ab" in the second column.
- With `print $1` we print the first column for the lines matched.